# Singular or plural form for negation

Tags: négation, pluriel

In the negation of

"J'ai mangé des pommes ce matin."

should we use the singular or plural?

> Je n'ai pas mangé de pomme ce matin.

or

> Je n'ai pas mangé de pomme**s** ce matin.

Similar question if we use aucune:

> Je n'ai mangé aucune pomme (*or* pomme(**s**)) ce matin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the plural in the first case ***je n'ai pas mangé de pommes ce matin*** because it negates a sentence where more than one apple is eaten (*j'ai mangé **des** pommes*.)

If you only eat at most one apple in the morning, you would say ***je n'ai pas mangé de pomme***. This sentence also negates ***j'ai mangé de la pomme***.

In the second one, it is singular ***je n'ai mangé aucune pomme***. Note however that the plural is possible in the cases where the noun has no singular form, or if its singular form has a different meaning, e.g.:

> *Je n'ai pris **aucunes** vacances*.

Answer (score 1):

If it's zero or one object, use singular. If it's more than one, or an undetermined number, use plural.

In your example, "de pommes" should be plural because "de" is short for "des", and "des pommes" is plural. Similarly, "aucune pomme" should be singular because "aucune" is clearly zero.